# Chrome page reloaded 5 seconds after saving the code

Tags: meteor, webstorm, liveedit

Using Meteor (todo example) and LiveEdit in WebStorm, the page reload every time i edit and save the code (after 5 seconds of delay).

Given that the LiveEdit is enabled why the page is reloaded?

How to fix the page reload delay ? is it possible to prevent it ?

Its seems it caused by the reload.js of Meteor-js, so its related to 
[Speed up Auto-reload in Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861880/speed-up-auto-reload-in-meteor-js)