# Why Meteor Hot Push Code still reload browser page?

Tags: meteor

According to http://info.meteor.com/blog/hot-code-pushes
Since Meteor 0.1.4, the server now hot-pushes changes to JS, CSS, and HTML files to the browser, automatically, without making you reload the page.

but as i asked here [Chrome page reloaded 5 seconds after saving the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957510/chrome-page-reloaded-5-seconds-after-saving-the-code)

i am using Meteor 1.2.1, and it still reloading the page !?

Comment: What is your question?  The hot-push is the page reload.